# Google OAuth not working when a user clicks from a LinkedIn link

Tags: browser, cross-browser, linkedin-api, google-oauth

When a user clicks a link to my site inside their LinkedIn app it doesn't take them to Safari or Chrome, it keeps them in an internal LinkedIn browser.

If the user then tries to create an account via Google OAuth they get the following error (see image).

Is there a way to prevent LinkedIn from opening a link in their proprietary browser, and take them to Safari or Chrome automatically? Or another workaround for this issue?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Neither you can restrict LinkedIn to open your site in other browser nor to stop google to throw the error. **To solve this problem**, You have to write a script which will open your website in the default browser of the user's device. Whenever user hit your website then check the web browser if it's chrome, safari or any other web browser then continue the request else force the user to open website in user's default browser using the script. That's it.
Hope this suggestion will help you.